# delete input select image preview using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I add image preview/delete before upload using jquery like this :

HTML is Here:

```
<input type='file' id='input1'>
<img id='imagepreview1' src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
```

JS is Here:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imagepreview1').prop('src', e.target.result).show().addClass('selected');
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#input1").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
    $('#imagepreview1').show();
});

var orig_src = $('#imagepreview1').prop('src');

$('#imagepreview1').click(function () {
    $('#input1').replaceWith($('#input1').clone(true));
    $('#imagepreview1').not('.selected').hide();
    $('#imagepreview1.selected').prop('src', orig_src).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Now, when I remove image with click this image input selected not remove and post data from my form. ho do can remove input select when I remove image?

Problem PIC (when I remove image and show preview):

[image]

NOTE: **(I check In FF not worked)**

DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/mkGSY/

Answer (score 2):

Just remove value from the `input` field.

```
$('#input1').val('');
```

Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkGSY/2/) here.

Comment: @WoIIe I am keen to know your solution

Comment: @Hiral: Here you go :)

Comment: @WoIIe: 1- whats your men `-1 for using jquery`? 2- please add demo here

Comment: @Hiral The coding style of the OP is sooooo bad. It is made by a typical jquery-script-kiddy who has no idea how to code **good** webapplications using javascript. Extremly slow and not structured. (My opinion)

Comment: @user3142680 Why should I add a demo? Just try it yourself?! It's just 1 line of code and it isn't very complex to implement.

Answer (score 0):

**Use native javascript**

If everybody just use jQuery for such simple tasks, nobody will learn how the browser implementation of ECMAScript is really working.

You can easily use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('input1').reset(); // My favourite
```

or if you prefer the idea of resetting the value of the input-element:

```
document.getElementById('input1').value = ""; // Will work just in major browsers
document.getElementById('input1').value = null; // Much more cross-browser compatible
```

**If you want to stick with jQuery**

... do yourself a favour and use this approach which is extremly bulletproof (instead of using `.val('')`:

```
var input = $("#input1");

function clearFileUpload() {
  input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
};
```